# How to install adobe flash player in windows phone app?

Tags: c#-4.0, air, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8

Hi i am working windows phone 8.i want to get some videos from my xml file but i cant play my video file.i got error like The Adobe Flash player or an HTML5 supported browser is required for video playback.Get the Latest Flash Player Learn more about upgrading to an HTML5 browser and i have attached image.please help me anyone.

[image]

I don't know how to get adobe flash player please help me anyone.Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe Flash Player isn't available for Windows Phone.

Comment: @user123 You may find a way to play the video without using Flash Player, but for sure there is no way to run the Flash Player on Windows Phone.