# Windows Phone 8 C# Playing Flash Videos

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, flash

The video I am trying to play does NOT support HTML5, it only supports flash video files (.swf), which doesn't work with the WebBrowser control -- unless I am missing something?

So, is there any already developed code libraries that allow playing flash videos (.swf) on Windows Phone 8? If not, how would you suggest going about getting flash files (.swf) to work on Windows Phone 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229017/how-to-install-adobe-flash-player-in-windows-phone-app)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a quick sample of how to have a fallback if HTML 5 is not supported:**

References:

- http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/simple-html5-video-flash-fallback-custom-controls/

  ```
          <video width="298" height="163" controls="controls"> 
          <source src="[URL TO MP4 File].mp4" type="video/mp4"></source> 
          <source src="[URL TO webm File FIrefox Support].webm" type="video/webm"></source> 
          <!--Embed Your Flash Object Here--> 
          <object classid="clsid:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" width="296" height="163"   align="middle"> 
          <param name="movie" value="[Flash File URL].swf.swf"> 
          <param name="quality" value="high"> 
          <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"> 
          <param name="play" value="true"> 
          <param name="loop" value="true"> 
          <param name="wmode" value="window"> 
          <param name="scale" value="showall"> 
          <param name="menu" value="true"> 
          <param name="devicefont" value="false"> 
          <param name="salign" value=""> 
          <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"> 
          <!--[if !IE]>--> 
          <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="[Flash File URL].swf" width="296" height="163"> 
          <param name="movie" value="[Flash File URL].swf"> 
          <param name="quality" value="high"> <param name="bgcolor" value="#cccccc"> <param name="play" value="true"> 
          <param name="loop" value="true"> <param name="wmode" value="window"> <param name="scale" value="showall"> 
          <param name="menu" value="true"> <param name="devicefont" value="false"> <param name="salign" value=""> 
          <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"> 
          <!--<![endif]--> 
          <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
          <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"> </a> <!--[if !IE]>--> </object> 
          <!--<![endif]--> 
          </object> 
          </video>
  ```