# How to use Adobe Flash in Windows Universal App

Tags: flash, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

Is [How to install adobe flash player in windows phone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229017/how-to-install-adobe-flash-player-in-windows-phone-app) still relevant? Can you use Adobe Flash in Windows 10 Universal Apps? If so how?

I want to load pandora or spotify on a Raspberry Pi through a Universal App. I am thinking since Windows 10 may have updated/enabled Adobe Flash.

Comment: There isn't any. No Flash player was ever available for Windows Phone or Windows Store applications, nor will be available in the future. In fact, it isn't available for Android any more. Even Adobe has [frozen Flash development](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2011/11/flash-focus.html)  apart from fixes

Comment: Besides, Windows IoT does *not* allow deployment of generic apps and addins like Flash. It really is about IoT, not about cheap general purpose computers. It doesn't even make sense to use Flash in an IoT device, unless you think about developing a digital signage device

Comment: @Bart how is mine the duplicate? Its 11 months older than the one you post

Comment: Can't close it the other way round, as this question didn't have an accepted answer. It's mainly a notification to anyone hitting this question, that there's a similar question with accepted answer on SO (as people usually keep looking until they have an accepted answer to 'trust'). If you rather have me bringing the answer over, I can do so.

Answer (score 1):

There's still no Adobe Flash player for Windows Store Apps(UWP), Windows Phone or Windows IoT Core.
Depending on your needs, you might try to use web APIs such as https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: I already know this is incorrect "no Adobe Flash player for Windows" .... I use this everyday on my Windows PC.

Comment: Well, the question was about Windows 10 Universal Apps. You can run Adobe Flash in Internet Explorer on Windows 10 Desktop, but not in a Windows 10 Universal App.

Comment: I need a source to accept your answer,

Comment: @SethKitchen there is no Flash for Windows Store apps (Phone, Windows, UWP). Such applications *can't* use plugins so there's no way to use Flash.  Actually, even Adobe has [frozen Flash development](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2011/11/flash-focus.html). Downvoting a correct answer because it isn't the desired one isn't proper SO ettiquete

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I downvoted it because he says there is no Adobe Flash player for Windows. He still has not edited that...

Comment: @SethKitchen for your tags, there isn't. The downvote was uncalled for, because there really is no Flash Player for the tags you used - actually for any mobile platform anymore. If there is a minunderstanding, it's about how Flash is (actually isn't) used in mobile platforms. As for IoT Core, the platform isn't meant to be a mobile platform at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your link. That is the best answer I've seen so far. I hope you will post an answer detailing how AIR can be used instead of Flash. And the problem is he lists my tags after he says Windows, so it looks as if there is no flash for Windows. He also posts no sources so it gives me no new information from the link I already posted

Comment: @SethKitchen I don't see where you're going. My answer apply in the context of your question & tags. There is no Flash plugin for Universal apps be it Windows, Windows Phone or else.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like u could could cook up your own flash shelled uwp prog and side strap it to a wp in dev mode. I'm gonna try this with a few old flash games when I have the time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter

That let's you turn exe's(win32) into uwp's... So the idea is that you package up a flash game with fp standalone and then run it through the desktop app converter. But this is using fp as a game engine. Not a multi media player plugin.

The problem is that it's all backwards and your putting shells into shells and fp and most flash games are resource greedy to begin with. :( but saving cool games, even flash games, is always worth a few hours of trying.

At any rate...

Moliplayer(that's really the name of it... Snot a typo...) app on winstore supposedly let's you run flash videos, but I havnt had a chance to fully test it. It gives you a browser that let's you save flash videos to you phone. Then you load em from there.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: Well its that or start up a web browser development for wp based entirely around fp without any support from adobe. But I dont want bog down your insightful comment with reality. So please, feel free to spout more boiler plate pr from adobe that everyone has already heard.